# Some kind of bubble sort in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I want to sort all the `<text>` elements by the value of the attribute `top`.

However an element should only be sorted if its previous sibling has a value of `top` that exceeds its own by 2 or more units.

For example, the following elements

```
<text top="100">text 1</text>
<text top="99">text 2</text>
<text top="100">text 3</text>
<text top="99">text 4</text>
<text top="35">text 5</text>
<text top="40">text 6</text>
```

should be transformed to:

```
<text top="35">text 5</text>
<text top="40">text 6</text>
<text top="100">text 1</text>
<text top="99">text 2</text>
<text top="100">text 3</text>
<text top="99">text 4</text>
```

So that the group:

```
<text top="100">text 1</text>
<text top="99">text 2</text>
<text top="100">text 3</text>
<text top="99">text 4</text>
```

remains as is after sorting.

I only use XSLT from time to time and only know the usual sorting approach:

```
<xsl:for-each select="text">
<xsl:sort select="@top" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="./node()|./@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But the result I want to achieve would require some kind of bubble sort.

Not sure whether it's doable with pure XSLT.
I have an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: *"an element should only be sorted if its previous sibling has a value of top that exceeds its own by 2 or more units."* That's not a complete rule, IMHO. It's easy to sort (only) the elements that meet the criteria. The question is where to position the sorted sequence. In your example, it's at the top - and I am not sure why.

Comment: P.S. Please state which version of XSLT you can use.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm not sure how to describe the sorting rule more exactly. Maybe I can say that those groups of adjacent <text> elements whose top values differ only in 1 unit should be left as is during sorting?... The sorting by the top attribute value should be in ascending order.

Comment: The adjacent grouping condition can be easily translated to XQuery 3.1 with a tumbling window I think, then, if I understand the requirements correctly, you could store each group in a map where the minimum `@top` serves as the map key, finally you can sort the sequence of maps by that key and then drop maps and solely return the items. See whether the examples at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqteB5/2, https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqteB5/1, https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqteB5/0 give the desired results. XQuery 3.1 is available with Saxon 9.8+

Comment: Down-voting because the specification is hopelessly incomplete.

Comment: I agree that the requeriments are incomplete. But this type of _"grouping contiguous values"_ arise occasionally, thus reformulated questions might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder whether in XSLT 2/3 it can just be done with an adequate `group-ending-with` pattern:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="limit" as="xs:integer" select="1"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="text" group-ending-with="text[abs(xs:decimal(following-sibling::text[1]/@top) - xs:decimal(@top)) > $limit]">
            <xsl:sort select="min(current-group()/@top/xs:decimal(.))"/>
            <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Based on the much simplified XQuery code

```
for tumbling window $group in root/text
start when true()
end $e next $ne when abs(xs:decimal($ne/@top) - xs:decimal($e/@top)) > 1
order by min($group/@top/xs:decimal(.))
return
  $group
```

Comment: This _"group ends if next is not contiguous"_ is another good answer. Do note that it sorts with respect to the whole population. It could also be reformulated as _"group starts if previus not contiguous"_

Answer (score 2):

As I undertand the requeriments are grouping and then sorting. Do note that it is assumed that groups which their elements have less than 2 units of increment are sorted among the others groups taking only the minimum into account (meaning that groups don't overlap).

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="*[text]">
    <xsl:for-each-group 
        select="text" 
        group-adjacent="boolean(
                            (preceding-sibling::text[1]
                            |following-sibling::text[1])
                            [abs(@top - current()/@top) &lt; 2])">
        <xsl:sort select="min(@top)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:perform-sort select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:sort select="@top" data-type="number"/>
                </xsl:perform-sort>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<text top="35">text 5</text>
<text top="40">text 6</text>
<text top="100">text 1</text>
<text top="99">text 2</text>
<text top="100">text 3</text>
<text top="99">text 4</text>
```

Test it in [here](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94Acsm7)

**EDIT**: not assuming only increasing sequence with `abs()` function.

Comment: That looks easier than I thought it is, but I wonder whether the result in http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94Acsm7/1 is the wanted result or whether the "group" (97, 96, 97) should not be moved before the one with 100, 99, 100, 99.

Comment: I think the problem as written is hopelessly under-specified, there is no point in attempting to write code that meets such a poorly-written specification.

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks. It almost works. But if the <text top="35">text 5</text> is the last element and <text top="40">text 6</text> its previous sibling before sorting than after sorting <text top="40">text 6</text> will be the last element. But the result should be the same as you Output:
I'll try to rework your snippet. Hopefully my XSLT knowledge will be enough :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see upcame comments.@ka3ak Yes, this answer assumes strictly increasing values. `abs()` functions solves that.